# Portable SQL for date arithmetic and comparison

Tags: php, sql, datetime

#### SQL

A table for storing user sessions:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions (
    user_id INT,
    expires TIMESTAMP
);
```

To create a session:

```
INSERT INTO sessions (user_id, expires) VALUES (:user_id,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '+15 minutes');
```

To retrieve a session:

```
SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE user_id = :user_id AND
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP < expires;
```

#### Questions

- Is this portable SQL?
  Will this work on any database available through the PHP [PDO extension](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php) (excluding SQLite)?
- Is this correct in different timezones? Across a daylight saving time adjustment?
  Any problem mixing `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (which includes timezone information) with a `TIMESTAMP` column (which doesn't)?

Comment: Or...keep dates/times as units since an epoch, makes the date arithmetic easy.  Likely easier to solve the final date projection at the app, than conditional SQL.

Comment: @Xepoch - I thought about that, but wanted to keep all date stuff in the database. Part of the logic being that a web server [doesn't have to keep time](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.18.1). I'm not sure why I thought the database server must.

Comment: @aaz, someone has to keep time.  Using an epoch date can be done through the DB, does not have to be in the app layer.  There are various opinions on this, but I've stated elsewhere that I have been saved too many times with integerial dates vs. formal date types.  In the end it's the same.

Comment: @Xepoch - I'm going to guess that if I asked whether `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` was portable, the replies would be fairly similar :) Also, I worry about 16-bit ints.

Comment: @aaz - that's my point, in that a simple set of DB-specific wrapper functions would be far less painful than the whole logic syntax of various date arithmetic syntax required.

Comment: @Xepoch, this is also wrapping, just with two functions (increment and compare) instead of one (Unix time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date/Time values are pretty problematic across SQL dialects, in my experience.

- Oracle supports `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP`, `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, and `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`.

  - DB2 supports DATE, TIME and TIMESTAMP.
  - SQL Server supports DATETIME and (recently) DATE. SQL Server has a `TIMESTAMP` data type, but it's not what you think it is.
  - MySQL supports DATE, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP, TIME and YEAR
  - PostgresSQL supports both TIMESTAMP and TIME, with and without timezone, along with DATE

If I had to deal with date/time values in an absolutely portable way, I'd store the value as a char/varchar in ISO8601 compact form

```
YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS[±HH:MM]
```

where the time component is 24h/military time. If you need timezone support, include the offset from UTC, or 'Z' to indicate Zulu (UTC) time. Strictly speaking, without the 'Z' suffix, the ISO 8601 date/time value is supposed to be interpreted as local time.

Depending on your needs, it might be worthwhile to break the date and time components out into separate columns.

ISO8601 gives you

- portability
- proper collation/comparison
- ease of parsing

Comment: Thanks. Another option is Unix time in an `INT` or `BIGINT`. Although `TIMESTAMP`, if it's available, feels more robust: no need to parse anything (in my example, since the date stays on the database side), no range issues (not sure if `INT` is guaranteed 32 bits), no extra storage space.

Answer (score 2):

Although it *is* standard SQL, there are DBMS (such as SQL Server) that do not support the standard. So the answer is yes and no.

Although I believe the ANSI standard way of writing an interval literal is: `INTERVAL '15' MINUTE`, not the way you wrote it

Comment: Yeah, I thought it looked too easy :) Regarding `INTERVAL` literals, I followed PostgreSQL documentation, and it interprets `INTERVAL '15' MINUTE` as 15 _seconds_ to minutely precision (i.e., 0).

Comment: `interval '15' minute` *will* return an interval of 15 **minutes** in PostgreSQL. But `interval '15' minutes` (note the 's' at the end) will indeed return an interval of 15 seconds. This is because *minutes* (which is not a valid qualifier for an interval) will be treated as an alias for that column and the default unit of seconds is applied to the literal. It's essentially the same as writing `interval '15' as minutes`.

Comment: Maybe it's version-dependent. Using 8.3 `interval '900' minutes` is a syntax error and `interval '900' minute` gives `00:15:00`.

Comment: `00:15:00` are 15 minutes not 15 seconds

Comment: Exactly, it's 900 seconds, not minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not support this. You would have to use the dataadd function. So the answer is no this is not protable SQL.

Comment: Looks like `DATEADD` is different from MySQL's `DATE_ADD`, different from SQLite's `DATETIME`, and neither is available in PostgreSQL...